How to find a plane through a point and a line without using vectors?
Given the plane $\pi$ represented by $2x + 3y - z + 5 = 0$ and a point $P(-1, -1, 2)$:

I need to verify whether the point $P$ belongs to the plane $\pi$;
I need to determine the plane $\pi'$, passing through the point $P$ and parallel to the plane $\pi$;
Given the line
$$
  s:\begin{cases} 2x - 3y = 0 \\ x + z = 0 \end{cases}
  $$
I need to find the plane that contains the point $P$ and the line $s$.


My work
1. Verifying whether $P$ belongs to the plane $\pi$:
To check if $P$ belongs to the plane, I substituted $x = -1$, $y = -1$, and $z = 2$ into the equation of the plane $\pi$:
$$
2(-1) + 3(-1) - 2 + 5 = -2 - 3 - 2 + 5 = -2
$$
Since $-2 \neq 0$, I concluded that the point $P$ does not belong to the plane $\pi$.

2. Finding the plane $\pi'$:
A plane parallel to $\pi$ has the same normal vector as $\pi$: $\vec{n} = (2, 3, -1)$.
The general equation of the plane $\pi'$ is:
$$
2x + 3y - z + d = 0
$$
To find $d$, I imposed that the plane passes through the point $P(-1, -1, 2)$:
$$
2(-1) + 3(-1) - 2 + d = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad -2 - 3 - 2 + d = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad d = 7
$$
Thus, the plane $\pi'$ is:
$$
\pi': \, 2x + 3y - z + 7 = 0
$$

3. Finding the plane containing $P$ and the line $s$:
The line $s$ is defined by the system:
$$
s:\begin{cases} 2x - 3y = 0 \\ x + z = 0 \end{cases}
$$
From this, I derived:

$x = \frac{3}{2}y$,
$z = -x$.

Next, I introduced the parameter $t$ by setting $y = t$. This gave:
$$
x = \frac{3}{2}t, \, y = t, \, z = -\frac{3}{2}t
$$
Thus, a direction vector of the line $s$ is:
$$
\vec{v_1} = \left(\frac{3}{2}, 1, -\frac{3}{2}\right)
$$
and a point on the line $s$ is the origin $(0, 0, 0)$, because when $t = 0$:  $x = 0$, $y = 0$, and $z = 0$.
The plane I am looking for must:

Pass through the point $P(-1, -1, 2)$;
Contain the direction vector $\vec{v_1}$;
Have a normal vector orthogonal to both $\vec{v_1}$ and the vector connecting $(0, 0, 0)$ to $P(-1, -1, 2)$.


Calculating the normal vector of the plane
To calculate the normal vector, I first computed the vector connecting $(0, 0, 0)$ to $P(-1, -1, 2)$:
$$
\vec{v_2} = P - (0, 0, 0) = (-1, -1, 2)
$$
The normal vector $\vec{n}$ to the plane is the cross product $\vec{v_1} \times \vec{v_2}$:
$$
\vec{n} = \begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\
\frac{3}{2} & 1 & -\frac{3}{2} \\
-1 & -1 & 2
\end{vmatrix}
$$
I computed the determinant of the minors:
$$
\vec{n} = \mathbf{i} \begin{vmatrix} 1 & -\frac{3}{2} \\ -1 & 2 \end{vmatrix}
- \mathbf{j} \begin{vmatrix} \frac{3}{2} & -\frac{3}{2} \\ -1 & 2 \end{vmatrix}
+ \mathbf{k} \begin{vmatrix} \frac{3}{2} & 1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{vmatrix}
$$

For $\mathbf{i}$, I computed:
$$
\begin{vmatrix} 1 & -\frac{3}{2} \\ -1 & 2 \end{vmatrix} = (1)(2) - (-1)(-\frac{3}{2}) = 2 - \frac{3}{2} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

For $\mathbf{j}$, I computed:
$$
\begin{vmatrix} \frac{3}{2} & -\frac{3}{2} \\ -1 & 2 \end{vmatrix} = \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)(2) - (-1)(-\frac{3}{2}) = 3 - \frac{3}{2} = \frac{3}{2}
$$

For $\mathbf{k}$, I computed:
$$
\begin{vmatrix} \frac{3}{2} & 1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{vmatrix} = \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)(-1) - (-1)(1) = -\frac{3}{2} + 1 = -\frac{1}{2}
$$


Thus:
$$
\vec{n} = \left(\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{3}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$

Equation of the plane
The equation of the plane is:
$$
\frac{1}{2}(x + 1) - \frac{3}{2}(y + 1) - \frac{1}{2}(z - 2) = 0
$$
Multiplying through by 2:
$$
x - 3y - z = 0
$$

Final Results

The point $P(-1, -1, 2)$ does not belong to the plane $\pi$.
The parallel plane $\pi'$ is:
$$
   2x + 3y - z + 7 = 0
   $$
The plane containing $P$ and the line $s$ is:
$$
   x - 3y - z = 0
   $$


My Questions
I would like confirmation if my solution is correct and understand how to do the part $3$ without using vectors.

The generic equation of the plane through $s$ and $P$ is $x+by+cz=0$. Insert here the coordinates of $P$ and of another point on $s$ (e.g. $B=(3,2,-3)$) and solve the resulting system for $b$ and $c$.

@Intelligentipauca Thanks for your suggestion! I followed your method and found the same solution :).

The equation of a plane is $ax+by+cz=d$. Since the line $s$ contains the origin, this would imply that $$d = a\cdot 0 + b \cdot 0 + c\cdot 0 =0$$
Now we pick a point different from the origin on $s$, for example, $Q(3,2,-3)$. The condition $P,Q$ contained in the plane yields
$$\begin{cases}-a-b+2c = 0\\
3a+2b-3c =0 \end{cases}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} b=-3a \\c=-a \end{cases} $$
Since $a,b,c$ can't be $0$ simultaneously, we can choose $a =1$, hence $b=-3$ and $c=-1$. The equation of the desired plane is then $x-3y-z=0$, which is same as your result.

Sorry, I'm just reading now :(. Anyway, thanks so much for the reply!

@mo-_- =)) There's no need to apologise, I am glad if it is helpful for you.
